# Passing Php Variables With jQuery load() function

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pull a portion of a plugin into the wordpress homepage using the jQuery .load() method and I'm a little tripped up on the syntax on how to just pull in a section of the page. Heres my code:

```
            //Get Current user and Home url
              global $current_user;
              get_currentuserinfo();
              $kd_bpuser = $current_user->user_login;
              $homeurl = get_home_url();
            ?>

            <script>
            //Pass home url and current user to javascript
              var bpUser = <?php echo json_encode($kd_bpuser); ?>;
              var bpUrl = <?php echo json_encode($homeurl); ?>;
              var bpFullUrl = bpUrl +"/members/" + bpUser + "/forums/subscriptions/"; 
              var bpData = "#bbp-author-unread-topics";
              // console.log(bpFullUrl);
              // console.log(bpUser);
              // console.log(bpUrl);
            </script>


            <div id="bbpress-forums">  

             <script type="text/javascript">

                  //pull in members subscriptions page unread forum topics
                  jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                    $("#bbpress-forums").load(bpFullUrl, bpData);
                  });

              </script>



            </div><!-- end bbpress-forums-->
```

Currently it just pulls in the whole page but I want it to just pull in this section: #bbp-author-unread-topics. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector portion of `load()` url needs to be part of the url string with a space separator. You are passing it as a separate argument

Try:

```
$("#bbpress-forums").load(bpFullUrl + ' ' +  bpData);
```

See example in [load() docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) under section *"Loading Page Fragments"*

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

Comment: Yep, that makes perfect sense. I have run into this problem before when trying to use load() but could never make sense of why it wouldn't work. This should be added to the .load() docs as an example. Thanks so much, checked it and its working fine.  You made my Friday :)

Comment: It is in docs, it's just a matter of concatenating strings properly

Comment: Yes, I went and read that but a code example would have done wonders. I noticed all the trolls are downgrading this post. I like this community but if its just for experts, I'll look elsewhere, I'm here to learn not deal with thoughtless, narcissistic idiots.

Comment: don't take it personal..you got your solution didn't you?